# Symfony2 deployment to production using Capistrano 3

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, capistrano, capistrano3

After getting my head around some local Symfony2 development I wanted to explore how to deploy to live environment and I decided to try Capistrano 3 and the Symfony plugin https://github.com/capistrano/symfony/.

I've followed a number of guides and read many SO questions/answers and I am able to get my files onto the live server.

I am using Dreamhost on a shared plan and have a web directory of home/myusername/mydomain/web.  After the Capistrano deploy the directory at home/myusername/mydomain looks like this:

current/

releases/

repo/

shared/

tmp/

web/ <--this is not the Symfony web directory but default created by Dreamhost.

However when I visit the site none of my routes work I just get 404s.  If i change the document root from /home/myusername/pickingorganic/web to to /home/myusername/pickingorganic/  then I can access my routes for example mydomain/current/web/login, but obviously I don’t want current/web to appear in the URL.

If I run

```
ls -la mydomain | grep "\->"
```

on the server I can see that the Capistano symlink from current directory seems to be in place correctly

```
current -> /home/myusername/mydomain/releases/20160112132605
```

I assume that my errors are somewhere in the Symfony web/.htaccess file (which is unmodified) or in my Capistrano settings.  I’ve put these below.  Any advice on where I am going wrong greatly appreciated.  Also if anyone has experience with the Capistrano Symphony plugin especially how to configure the settings shown here https://github.com/capistrano/symfony/#settings correctly that would be fantastic; I’ve searched for examples or tutorials but not really come across anything.

**deploy.rb**

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

#set :tmp_dir, "#{fetch(:home)}/tmp"
set :tmp_dir, "/home/myusername/mydomain/tmp"

set :application, 'storyproject'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:githubid/githubproject-project.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/home/myusername/mydomain'

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files,
[]).push('app/config/parameters.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('vendor/bundle')

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5


#namespace :deploy do

# after :restart, :clear_cache do
#  on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
  # Here we can do anything such as:
  # within release_path do
  #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
  # end
# end
#end

#end

namespace :deploy do

desc 'composer install'
task :composer_install do
    on roles(:web) do
        within release_path do
            execute 'composer', 'install', '--no-dev', '--optimize-   autoloader'
        end
    end
end

after :updated, 'deploy:composer_install'

desc 'Restart application - does nothing, see comments below'
task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
        # This is present b/c 'cap production deploy' is blowing up w/o it.
        # Not sure what's up with that, the Google hasn't helped, and I'm tired
        # of screwing with it.  It stays in for now.
    end
end

end
```

**production.rb**

```
set :stage, :production

role :web, %w{sshuser@mydomain}
role :app, %w{sshuser@mydomain}

set :ssh_options, {
forward_agent: true
}


# Symfony environment
set :symfony_env,  "prod"

# Symfony application path
set :app_path,              "app"

# Symfony web path
set :web_path,              "web"

# Symfony log path
set :log_path,              fetch(:app_path) + "/logs"

# Symfony cache path
set :cache_path,            fetch(:app_path) + "/cache"

# Symfony config file path
set :app_config_path,       fetch(:app_path) + "/config"

# Controllers to clear
set :controllers_to_clear, ["app_*.php"]

# Files that need to remain the same between deploys
#set :linked_files,          []

# Dirs that need to remain the same between deploys (shared dirs)
set :linked_dirs,           [fetch(:log_path), fetch(:web_path) +     "/uploads"]

# Dirs that need to be writable by the HTTP Server (i.e. cache, log dirs)
set :file_permissions_paths,         [fetch(:log_path), fetch(:cache_path)]

# Name used by the Web Server (i.e. www-data for Apache)
set :file_permissions_users, ['www-data']

# Name used by the Web Server (i.e. www-data for Apache)
set :webserver_user,        "www-data"

# Method used to set permissions (:chmod, :acl, or :chgrp)
set :permission_method,     false

# Execute set permissions
set :use_set_permissions,   false

# Symfony console path
set :symfony_console_path, fetch(:app_path) + "/console"

# Symfony console flags
set :symfony_console_flags, "--no-debug"

# Assets install path
set :assets_install_path,   fetch(:web_path)

# Assets install flags
set :assets_install_flags,  '--symlink'

# Assetic dump flags
set :assetic_dump_flags,  ''

fetch(:default_env).merge!(symfony_env: fetch(:symfony_env))

# server-based syntax
# ======================
# Defines a single server with a list of roles and multiple properties.
# You can define all roles on a single server, or split them:

# server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}, my_property: :my_value
# server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app web}, other_property: :other_value
# server 'db.example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{db}

# role-based syntax
# ==================

# Defines a role with one or multiple servers. The primary server in each
# group is considered to be the first unless any  hosts have the primary
# property set. Specify the username and a domain or IP for the server.
# Don't use `:all`, it's a meta role.

# role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}, my_property: :my_value
# role :web, %w{user1@primary.com user2@additional.com}, other_property: :other_value
# role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}

# Configuration
# =============
# You can set any configuration variable like in config/deploy.rb
# These variables are then only loaded and set in this stage.
# For available Capistrano configuration variables see the documentation page.
# http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/
# Feel free to add new variables to customise your setup.


# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
# You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
# limited set of options, consult the Net::SSH documentation.
# http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start
#
# Global options
# --------------
#  set :ssh_options, {
#    keys: %w(/home/rlisowski/.ssh/id_rsa),
#    forward_agent: false,
#    auth_methods: %w(password)
#  }
#
# The server-based syntax can be used to override options:
# ------------------------------------
# server 'example.com',
#   user: 'user_name',
#   roles: %w{web app},
#   ssh_options: {
#     user: 'user_name', # overrides user setting above
#     keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
#     forward_agent: false,
#     auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
#     # password: 'please use keys'
#   }
```

**Symfony web/.htaccess**

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
# If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
# project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
# resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
# work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
# the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
# (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
# rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
# endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
# redirect -> request -> ...).
# So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
# to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
# environment variable, you have 2 choices:
# - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
# - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
#   following RewriteCond (best solution)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
    # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
    # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
    # and the generated links can still be used.
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So just change your root to `/home/myusername/pickingorganic/current/web`. Any troubles to do that?

Comment: @malcolm thanks.  yes I can do that and it works but I wasn't thinking that I would need to do that to accommodate the directory structure Capistrano creates.  If that's the way Capistrano suggests you deal with this issue then I'm happy to accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: I never used capistrano, but point your domain to directory where is main `.php` or `.html` file is the basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folders structure looks like this:

```
├── current -> /home/myusername/mydomain/releases/20150120114500/
├── releases
│   ├── 20150080072500
│   ├── 20150090083000
│   ├── 20150100093500
│   ├── 20150110104000
│   └── 20150120114500
├── repo
│   └── <VCS related data>
├── revisions.log
└── shared
    └── <linked_files and linked_dirs>
```

From documentation:

> **current** is a symlink pointing to the latest release. This symlink is updated at the end of a successful deployment. If the deployment fails in any step the current symlink still points to the old release.

Your main `app.php` file is located in `/home/myusername/mydomain/current/web/app.php` and you should point your domain exactly to that directory, otherwise you must add directories in path to access that file (eg. `mydomain.com/myusername/mydomain/current/web`).

Just point your domain to `/home/myusername/mydomain/current/web/`.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache you have to make sure you have symlinks following enabled.

```
<Directory /home/myusername/mydomain>
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```